# Looking for words/expressions less strong than "fail to"

Tags: word-request

Take this expression:

- A **fails to** do X

To me, "fails to" means that A is completely unsuccessful in doing X.

I am looking for less strong words/expressions that convey the meaning that A is partly unsuccessful.

Comment: What is the task??

Comment: What's wrong with ***X doesn't do Y***? If that's still "too strong", how about ***X doesn't quite do Y** [completely]*?

Comment: @christianjackson  Are you literally looking for a [modal](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/modal-verbs)?  If so, why does it specifically have to be a modal?

Comment: An adverb works best, in my opinion. X partly fails to do Y. oR: failed in part. Or: phrasal verb: falls short of [verb+ing]

Comment: Whoever downvoted me is completely wrong. To fail to do something, said more gently is to fall short of doing something. [grhh]

Comment: There is no modal. If you use ""do fail to", you are merely emphasizing that fact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some alternatives might be:

- Universities are **deficient** at teaching how to communicate.
- Universities **struggle** to teach [students] how to communicate. *(suggests they at least try)*
- Universities **could do more** in teaching how to communicate.
- Universities **could go further** in teaching how to communicate.
- Universities **fall short** at teaching how to communicate.
- Universities **only go so far** at teaching how to communicate.
- Universities **have a degree of success** at teaching how to communicate.
- Universities teach how to communicate **to a degree**.

Comment: @christianjackson It depends. When used with a measure you might use OF or BY, but that usage implies that you failed (eg 'he fell short of winning by minutes'). You can also say something or somebody "falls short of the mark" to mean they failed to reach the required standard. But besides that, we use "fall short" as a verb phrase on its own to mean that something hasn't quite made it all the way, so you can use it with 'at' if you choose to. Another way to phrase it would be "In teaching how to communicate, universities fall short". Also, it's not my only suggestion, and I've added more!

Comment: @christianjackson It is fall short of [noun] OR fall short of {gerund]

Comment: @lambie If you fall short *of* something then you fail to reach it. If you fall short of the finishing line, you haven't finished. In that case, this isn't the right idiom for the OP who wants to say they did not fail. Actually, 'fall short ' is often used in isolation to simply mean something did not go all the way, so if it can be used without any preposition following it then I would argue *any* preposition could follow it. Whatever you think on that is irrelevant, it isn't my only suggestion.

Comment: No, you are mistaken.  The OP wants to say fail in a less obvious way, less strong. "convey the meaning that A is partly unsuccessful".

Comment: @lambie If you fall short of the finish line in a race, not only do you not win, but you do not even receive a ranking for having completed it. How is that 'partly successful'?

Comment: You could say "are bad at doing something" if you feel that "fall short at doing something" is inappropriate for your purpose.

Comment: @christianjackson It is defined in the dictionary: fail to meet an expectation or standard. So "Universities fail to meet the standard of teaching etc.=Universities fall short of teaching etc.".

Answer (score 4):

One common option to avoid using a word with a strongly negative connotation would be to replace it with a word meaning the opposite in the negative.

Instead of "They failed to convince the commission" you might put "They didn't [quite] succeed in convincing the commission" or "They didn't [quite] manage to convince the commission."

You might might also add the adverb "properly" (or a synomym) to your negative construction, especially if you want to retain a little of the critical nuance carried by "fail".

"University X doesn't properly/comprehensively teach students how to communicate."

Or you could add a qualifier to 'fail' to soften it.

"University X fails to properly/fully/comprehensively teach students how to communicate."

The last one is a split infinitive. But who cares about that since Star Trek!

Comment: For non-Trekkies, the famous split infinitive was: "*To boldly* go where no man has gone before"

Answer (score 2):

I think that your expression "are poor at" is perfectly fine English:

- Universities **are poor at** recruiting foreign students *(= partial failure)*

Instead of:

- Universities **fail to** recruit foreign students *(= complete failure)*

Answer (score 1):

Maybe "A **struggles with/to** X".

For example,

> [His performance on standardized measures of academic achievement suggest that he struggles with reading comprehension and applied mathematics problems.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he%20struggles%20with%22)

> [He struggles with reading music. James is learning music by ear and watching Lauren's fingers to know which notes to play. That is how he figures out “how the music goes.”](https://books.google.com/books?id=C2fLCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT245&dq=%22he%20struggles%20with%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjjsJSB94X9AhX6mokEHdsLDy0Q6AF6BAgIEAI)

> [She is often uncertain of what technologies are available to meet her needs, and she struggles to learn the technologies on her own.](https://books.google.com/books?id=NKncAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA78&dq=%22she%20struggles%20to%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_65bM94X9AhWijYkEHaDJATwQ6AF6BAgIEAI)

Comment: @christianjackson -  *Struggle* is the best answer provided so far.  *Universities struggle to teach communications.*  Are you not fully understanding all the definitions of *struggle*?  *To attempt but fall short,* is a common, modern usage for *struggle*.

Answer (score 1):

**fall short of** doing something:

- Universities fall short of teaching students to communicate.
- His book on existentialism falls short of conveying the principles of that philosophy.

or fail partly or in part

**fall short**

**fail to meet an expectation or standard.**
"the total vote fell short of the required two-thirds majority"

[Oxford Dictionary via Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=fall%20short%20of&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS1030US1031&oq=fall%20short%20of&aqs=chrome.0.0i512l10.2359j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I don't think your first sentence is a natural use of "fall short". 
Something like "Universities fall short [at/when it comes to/of [par/standards/scratch] when] teaching students to communicate" would be more common.

Comment: @Jaime You put in of, of has to be following by an gerund, which is what I used. I was just giving examples not claiming that is the only way to write it.

Comment: I put in 'of' with a choice of abstract nouns. "falling short of teaching students to communicate" doesn't seem a natural use of the expression. I'm sorry.  "Fall short of" is normally followed by some fairly close synonym for "benchmark".

Comment: I think he falls short of answering the question.

Comment: You're right on that one! It does sound idiomatic, but it refers to a metaphorical line that can be notionally reached. "Teaching" seems to me an activity rather than achieving a goal or standard. Though you could argue back and forth about it I suppose.  I would continue to say, however, that your original really doesn't sound idiomatic to me.

Comment: @Jaime Whatever. The point is the idiom **to fall short of** and that idiom can be followed by a noun or gerund.

Comment: You've demonstrated that. And I'm grateful to have learnt something. Though my original point stands.

Comment: 95% of Small Businesses Fall Short of **Meeting** Goals, yet 77% Are Confident in Their Ability to Execute [Google]

Comment: Yep. More benchmarks.

Answer (score 0):

You could say **are bad at doing something**.

Answer (score -1):

**Inadequate**

- A is *inadequate to* (accomplish/do/complete/satisfy/finish/perform/etc.) B . . .
- A *inadequately* (accomplishes/does/completes/fulfills/etc.) B . . .

**Word bank of near equivalents**

Insufficient, imperfect, imprecise, inefficacious, ineffective, unsatisfactory, unfaithful